# Is there a way to fill with different height water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there way to use the fill command to fill a area with water at different levels?

Comment: What do you mean by different levels? Going up and down like a tide, or moving sideways like a wave?

Comment: up and down. I probably need to use block data or block value in the fill command but I don't know were to add the numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the [Minecraft Wiki for Water](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Water) and it gives you some text about bits and numbers, which I thought were confusing:

> If bit 0x8 is set, this liquid is "falling" and only spreads downward. At this level, the lower bits are essentially ignored, since this block is then at its highest fluid level.
>
> The lower three bits are the fluid block's level. 0x0 is the highest fluid level (not necessarily filling the block - this depends on the neighboring fluid blocks above each upper corner of the block). Data values increase as the fluid level of the block drops: 0x1 is next highest, 0x2 lower, on through 0x7, the lowest fluid level. Along a line on a flat plane, water drops one level per meter from the source.

Blah blah blah.

I messed around with this command:

```
/fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ water 1-8
```

And I got this result:
[image]

Note that it starts from 8, not 1, and 8 is a full block but 7 is the smallest.
For some reason, everything else from 9-15 is just a full block of water. I couldn't get anything higher than the water level for #1.

Comment: I there a way to make the water level higher the 1?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, this is all I could scavenge out of the huge wiki page.